# I want to test presence of objects in Decision Table

Tags: drools

Drools 5 - I want to test for presence of BLueReport object AND SSCData object, and if both are present, then assign some default values.  I've tried a number of conditions, but no luck.

```
6-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 7| CONDITION           | CONDITION           | ACTION                          |
 8| exists BlueReport   | exists SSCData      | sscData.setORIG_LOC_CD($param); |
 9|                     |                     | Set Location Code               |
10|                     |                     | "SLR"                           |
11-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

... and I also tried this:

```
     6-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 7| CONDITION           | CONDITION           | ACTION                          |
 8| exists BlueReport   | exists SSCData      | sscData.setORIG_LOC_CD($param); |
 9| eval(true)          | eval(true)          | Set Location Code               |
10|                     |                     | "SLR"                           |
11-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have a test agent that compiles the Excel DT to a DRL file and it reports this as a result:

```
//generated from Decision Table
import mypackage.cost.model.*;
// rule values at A11, header at A6
rule "DIV 07"
    salience 65525
    when
    then
        sscData.setORIG_LOC_CD("SLR");
        sscData.setSERVICE_CD("SLIC");
        sscData.appendRuleAudit(drools.getRule().getName());
end
```

I have arrived at this, but don't know what to put in Row 9:
[image: Not sure what to enter in Row9 (B9 and C9)]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some specific `SSCData` bound to a variable otherwise you cannot reference a fact for changing its fields. This modifies `all`SSCDat` in Working Memory:

```
rule x
when
  exists BlueReport()
  sscData: SSCDate()
then
    sscData.setORIG_LOC_CD("SLR");
    sscData.setSERVICE_CD("SLIC");
    sscData.appendRuleAudit(drools.getRule().getName());
end
```

You cannot bind to the pattern after `exists` as this succeeds once for an arbitrary positive number of matching facts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with for the final solution:
[image: My solution:]